# Parse embedded string form JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, parsing, url

I have a Rails 3 application and I am using the following code to parse a JSON post:

```
email_payload = JSON.parse(params[:payload])
Result.create(:from => email_payload['from'], :from_name => email_payload['from_name'], :from_address => email_payload['from_address'], :date => email_payload['date'], :html_body => email_payload['html_body'], :priority => email_payload['priority'], :spam_status => email_payload['spam_status'], :subject => email_payload['subject'])
```

The JSON post data is as follows:

```
payload{ "address_identifier": null, "attachments": [ [ "twitter.png", "image/png", 3029, "http://api.deliverhq.com/api/incoming/attachment/7gdd71wo75/5772412/0" ] ], "cc": null, "date": "Thu, 25 Oct 2012 22:04:20 +0100"
```

I am trying to work out how to parse the URL, in this case `http://api.deliverhq.com/api/incoming/attachment/7gdd71wo75/5772412/0`, and then enter the URL into the database.

```
:url => email_payload['attachments']
```

won't work because there is multiple values within attachment and:

```
email_attachments_payload = JSON.parse(params[:payload][:attachments])
:url => email_attachments_payload['URL']
```

won't work because the URL doesn't have an identifier. For this particular application there should only ever be one attachment, therefore selecting .first may be an option if that's possible.

Any pointers would be appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

Adding:

```
email_payload[:attachments][0][4]
```

results in the following exception error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method []' for nil:NilClass
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
def receive_fax
    if request.get?
        render :text => "hello"
    elsif request.post?   
      email_payload = JSON.parse(params[:payload])     
      Fax.create(:from => email_payload['from'], :from_name => email_payload['from_name'], :from_address => email_payload['from_address'], :date => email_payload['date'], :html_body => email_payload['html_body'], :priority => email_payload['priority'], :spam_status => email_payload['spam_status'], :subject => email_payload['subject'], :fax => email_payload[:attachments][0][3])
      render :text => "success"
    else
      render :text => "error"
    end
  end
```

Comment: You seem to be switching between `attachment` and `attachments`, is it singular or plural?

Comment: `email_payload[:attachments]` is a 1-element array with a 4-element array in it, the last of which is a URL. What you want is to get that URL? Can't you just use `email_payload[:attachments][0][4]`? If not then you have to be more specific about the constraints.

Comment: Yeah doing that throws an exception. `TypeError: can't convert Symbol into Integer`

Comment: Sorry - the actual error is `NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Sorry that should be `email_payload[:attachments][0][3]`. It works fine in the console.

Comment: Sorry that should be `email_payload['attachments'][0][3]`. I'm not awake today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try: email_payload['attachments'][0][3]

It appears that the problem may be the difference between :attachments (a symbol) and 'attachments' (a string).

Answer (score 2):

In irb:

```
require 'json'

email_payload = JSON.parse('{ "address_identifier": null, "attachments": [ [ "twitter.png", "image/png", 3029, "http://api.deliverhq.com/api/incoming/attachment/7gdd71wo75/5772412/0" ] ], "cc": null, "date": "Thu, 25 Oct 2012 22:04:20 +0100" }')
#=> {"address_identifier"=>nil, "attachments"=>[["twitter.png", "image/png", 3029, "http://api.deliverhq.com/api/incoming/attachment/7gdd71wo75/5772412/0"]], "cc"=>nil, "date"=>"Thu, 25 Oct 2012 22:04:20 +0100"}
email_payload['attachments'][0][3]
#=> "http://api.deliverhq.com/api/incoming/attachment/7gdd71wo75/5772412/0"
```

If that doesn't work then there's something else going on that you haven't described above.

UPDATE: in the hash returned from `JSON.parse`, the `attachments` key should be a string (`'attachments'`), not a symbol (`:attachments`). Updated my answer above.

Comment: Is the way I'm parsing the payload causing an error? I've updated my question with the full code.

Comment: Very sorry, I miscopied my code from the console. It should be `email_payload['attachments'][0][3]` - i.e. `'attachments'` (a string) not `:attachments` (a symbol).